# How do I point the mouse to a specific part of the page and then scroll? (Puppeteer)

Tags: javascript, puppeteer

The URL I'm talking about is https://www.vudu.com/content/movies/movieslist. I'm trying to scroll through the part where the movies are. When I use the following code, it doesn't work.

```
await page.evaluate( () => {
        window.scrollBy(0, window.innerHeight);
    });
```

I think this is because you naturally have to hover over the movies before that part can scroll. How can I solve this problem? Thanks!

My full code:

```
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');

(async () => {
    const browser = await puppeteer.launch({ headless: false });
    const page = await browser.newPage();
    await page.setViewport({ width: 1280, height: 800 });
    url = "https://www.vudu.com/content/movies/movieslist"
    await page.goto(url, {waitUntil: 'load'});
    await page.evaluate( () => {
        window.scrollBy(0, window.innerHeight);
    });
    await page.waitFor(2000);
})()
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`mouse.move()`](https://github.com/puppeteer/puppeteer/blob/main/docs/api.md#mousemovex-y-options) for this, but it seems this would not fix the issue as the document body is not scrollable. You need to find the scrollable element to scroll just it:

```js
'use strict';

const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');

(async function main() {
  try {
    const browser = await puppeteer.launch({ headless: false, defaultViewport: null });
    const [page] = await browser.pages();

    await page.goto('https://www.vudu.com/content/movies/movieslist');
    await page.waitForSelector('.nr-pt-40');

    const data = await page.evaluate(() => {
      const container = document.querySelector('.nr-pt-40');
      container.scrollBy(0, container.clientHeight);
    });

    // await browser.close();
  } catch (err) {
    console.error(err);
  }
})();
```

Comment: It worked! Thank you so much! One more thing: how can I make it continue to scroll until it gets to the very end of the content? I put it into a for loop lol but I was wondering if there was a better way

Comment: You can use [a tip from MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/scrollHeight#Determine_if_an_element_has_been_totally_scrolled): `while (container.scrollHeight - container.scrollTop !== container.clientHeight) { /* scroll */ }`.

Answer (score 3):

It's not the window that you need to scroll, but the div that wraps the thunbnails.

Try getting a handle to the wrapper using:

```
var first = document.querySelector(".contentPosterWrapper");
var wrapper = first.parentNode.parentNode;
wrapper.scrollBy(0, 500);
```